# How to replace specific string patern in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, replace

I have on table xyz, with field named "Question", which is contain the value like

"Is this image good on wall `<img alt="" src="../Images/29/29/jpg>`, please provide opinion."

when i fire select query on this table, the result should be look like this

"Is this image good on wall `[Question_Image],` please provide opinion."

Means i want to replace img tag with `[Question_Image]` text in select query

Thank in Advance...

Comment: i had try to use REPLACE function, but i want to know that, it is possible to user regx with replace in select query...so i can find specific substring and replace it

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better idea to store that placeholder `[Question_Image]` in database instead of `<img>` tag? Maybe you should replace `<img alt="" src="../Images/29/29/jpg">` with `[Question_Image]` **before** you insert it into database ?

Anyways - have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: that is a good idea, but only one place i want to replace this <img> tag, else where in software i am fetch data with <img> tag...it is better to replace on thing then many....by the way thanks for reply